# How to get rid of ConfigParser is not defined error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, configparser

Below is my settings.py file.

```
import configparser
import os
import sys

import djcelery
import redis
import raven

djcelery.setup_loader()

# this should disable some of the warnings sam
# import urllib3
# urllib3.disable_warnings()

#####################################################

# this has been moved to config/tools.conf


#####################################################
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir)))[0]
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

ctx = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
ctx.read('%s/config/tools.conf' % PROJECT_PATH)
```

When I run the command `python manage.py celeryd` I keep on getting the below error can any one suggest what is going wrong here?

```
File "/opt/tools/core/settings.py", line 22, in <module>
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
NameError: name 'ConfigParser' is not defined
```

Comment: You are importing `configparser`, not `ConfigParser`. That was a change made between Python 2 and Python 3; it looks like you either did not update the *use* of `ConfigParser`, or simply followed an example intended for Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please below changes for the code to work properly.

change

`config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`

to

`config = configparser.ConfigParser()`

And then change

```
ctx = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
```

to

```
ctx = configparser.RawConfigParser()
```

Comment: This is the new error now  ctx = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
NameError: name 'ConfigParser' is not defined

Comment: I'd recommend to use an IDE with a linter and syntax highlighting. It should flag these kinds of errors straight away ;)